# Actually I am learning Laravel I need some Advance lavel resource. any body can help me

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-3

Actually I am learning Laravel I need some Advance level resource. any body can help me .I complete beginner level .

Comment: This is a QA site designed to help developers overcome **specific** problems with help from the community. There are plenty of learning resources available for Laravel including excellent documentation at http://www.laravel.com I suggest you head there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added few resources, which will definitely help you.

1. [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick)
2. [Cribbb Tutorial](http://culttt.com/tag/cribbb/page/9/), Start from page 9 and go all the way to 1. You will learn alot from here.
3. [Laracast Tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons)